# Implementing a 64bit integer using 32bit integers

Tags: 64-bit, 32bit-64bit, ansi-c

I am implementing an opcua server from specification. Opcua encodes datetime as a 64bit signed integer. The server will run on a 32bit embedded system that doesn't include(support) standard 64bit integers. 
I've tried looking online but i can't see useful articles on the subject. I also know that floating point numbers can be implemented from an open stadard from IEEE , but i don't seem to find a standardized representation for 64bit integers. 
I am using ansi C for the project.
Where can i get some sort of material,content to get me started on the task ?

Answer (score 1):

You can implement a 64 bit integer using 2 32 bit integers in *exactly* the same way that you can implement a 2-digit integer from 2 1-digit integers. In other words, what you have is nothing but a 2-"digit" number in base 2<sup>32</sup>.

If you know how to count beyond 9 using only digits 0-9, then you know how to count beyond 2<sup>32</sup> using only "digits" 0-2<sup>32</sup>, because it is the exact same thing.

Comment: do you mind sharing a little code snippet so i have something to build on top of ?

Comment: `234 = 4*10**0 + 3*10**1 + 2*10**2`. In general, a number written in base `b` as `x_0 x_1 x_2 x_3 … x_n` has the value `x_n * b**0 + x_n-1 * b**1 + x_n-2 * b**2 + … + x_0 * b**n`. Addition of two such numbers performed by adding `x_n` to `y_n`, `x_n-1` to `y_n-1` and so on, carrying over any overflow to the next place, if the result is larger than `b-1`. Multiplication is done place-wise and then adding together the intermediate results. This is essentially primary school stuff.